# How do I create a macro in Excel to replace data on a sheet with specific row orders from another sheet with filtered row data?

Tags: excel, vba

**Details:** I have a worksheet that keeps track of jobs (Sheet 1).  This is running on a macro that extracts data from another worksheet (Sheet 2).  Sheet 2 contains data for all the possible workstations, and I have separate tabs in the workbook that are copies of Sheet 1, but for each individual workstation.

Currently, I have the macro successfully set up to add lines to Sheet 1 if it exists on Sheet 2 but not Sheet 1.  That code is shown below.  I do this by first filtering the data on Sheet 2 per column F (workstation name), then checking against Sheet 1's list of job names per column I against Sheet 2's job names in column K.  If the job name already exists on Sheet 1, it is deleted off of Sheet 2.  After all the existing ones are deleted, it then copies the remaining lines on Sheet 2 over to the first available blank spaces in Sheet 1.  Sheet 2 then deletes itself.

Extra info to help:

Sheet 2 is copying from columns G to X

Sheet 1 is pasting from columns E to V

Edit note: I will clear out the .select lines in the final code.

**Goal:** It has been requested that even if the job already exists on Sheet 1, to copy the line over anyway because some of the other information may have been updated on Sheet 2.  I have been unable to find the series of commands necessary to add to the existing code that will allow it to copy the row of information based on if it exists without changing its order on Sheet 1.
What I mean by this: It would be simple to just delete all of Sheet 1 and copy all rows over from Sheet 2.  The row order on Sheet 1 is crucial to be kept as is, so each line on Sheet 2 needs to be checked one at a time to update Sheet 1's line in its current position.  If it doesn't exist, then it still needs to add the full row over to Sheet 1 at the first open space.

I have had some luck with filtering Sheet 1 as well and referencing a cell for a match, but it would only work on the first row, and the code was very long and repetitive so I didn't want to go with it.

2/3/22 Edit: Got the code to work as intended, though it isn't the cleanest execution.

```
Sub Macro1()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
Workbooks.Open Application.GetOpenFilename 'Click on Exported File with updates

Range("F3").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A4:Z" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Workstation Name" 'change per workstation tab
End With

ActiveSheet.Move Before:=Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets(1)

Dim lr As Long
Dim chklr As Long
Dim rngtochk As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim fromws As Worksheet
Dim chktows As Worksheet
Dim iLastRow As Integer

Set fromws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set chktows = Sheets("Workstation Tab")
lr = fromws.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
iLastRow = fromws.Range("G4").Top

For i = lr To 2 Step -1 'Loop start
lr = fromws.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
iLastRow = fromws.Range("G4").Top

    fromws.Activate
    Range("G4:X" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Range("G" & Selection.Row & ":X" & Selection.Row).Copy
        chktows.Activate
            Columns("AF:AH").ColumnWidth = 1 'Column manipulation required for some reason
            Columns("AJ:AN").ColumnWidth = 1
            Columns("AP:AQ").ColumnWidth = 1
        chktows.Range("AC2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        chktows.Range("E4").AutoFilter
    
    If chktows.Range("AC2") = "Column Header" Then 'Loop exit command
            chktows.Range("AC2:AU2").ClearContents
            Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
            Columns("AF:AH").ColumnWidth = 0
            Columns("AJ:AN").ColumnWidth = 0
            Columns("AP:AQ").ColumnWidth = 0
        chktows.AutoFilterMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With chktows 'Continue loop
        .Range("B3:S" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=chktows.Range("AC2")
        End With
    currcell = Cells(i, 11).Value
    chklr = chktows.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngtochk = chktows.Range("I4:I" & chklr)
    Set Rng = chktows.Range("E4:E55").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
    If Rng = "" Then 'Check if line update or new line add at bottom
        chktows.Range("E4").AutoFilter
        chktows.Range("AC2:AU2").Copy
    LastRow = chktows.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        chktows.Range("E" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        chktows.Range("AC2:AU2").ClearContents
            
            fromws.Activate
            Range("G4:X" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Range("G" & Selection.Row & ":X" & Selection.Row).Delete
    Else

        chktows.Activate
    LastRow = chktows.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("AC2:AU2").Copy
        Range("E4:E54").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("E4").AutoFilter
        Range("AC2:AU2").ClearContents
        
            fromws.Activate
            Range("G4:X" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Range("G" & Selection.Row & ":X" & Selection.Row).Delete
    End If
Next
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
            Columns("AF:AH").ColumnWidth = 0
            Columns("AJ:AN").ColumnWidth = 0
            Columns("AP:AQ").ColumnWidth = 0
chktows.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing if you use "worksheet" where you mean "workbook".  Also easier for us to follow your code if you take out the "select" and use explicit references, so we don't have to figure what sheet happens to be active at any point in the process.  If you want to match rows and those rows both have a unique "Id" then using `Application.Match()` is probably the most straightforward way to do that.

Comment: I don't use workbook because it is immediately made into a tab within the same workbook.  It becomes a sheet at that point, thus the wording.  I was able to get it working how I wanted.  There are some things that I would rather not be in it, such as column width changing, repeating some lines, and having to use .select when it wouldn't combine on a single line, but trying to compress them to look better made it break.  I'm good with this, it doesn't need to be optimized beyond how it functions, but further suggestions for future viewings are welcome.